# Maximum of $f(x)=\frac{2x\sqrt{(x+1)}}{(9x^2+3)^{\frac{1}{4}}}+\frac{(1-2x)\sqrt{2-2x}}{(9(1-2x)^2+3)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$ on the interval $[0,1/2]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I would like to find the maxima of the following function in one variable :
$$f(x)=\frac{2x\sqrt{(x+1)}}{(9x^2+3)^{\frac{1}{4}}}+\frac{(1-2x)\sqrt{2-2x}}{(9(1-2x)^2+3)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$$
on the interval $[0,1/2]$. I have already checked that it must occur at $1/3$, but could someone
give me a proper method of proving it (ideally without using computation engines ?). The problem here is obviously that the derivative of this function is not nice-looking at all and i do not wish to "play" with it.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S $$f(x)=\frac{2x\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{4}(1+3)(9x^2+3)}}+\frac{(1-2x)\sqrt{2-2x}}{\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{4}(1+3)(9(1-2x)^2+3)}}\leq$$
$$\geq\frac{2x\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{4}(3x+3)^2}}+\frac{(1-2x)\sqrt{2-2x}}{\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{4}(3(1-2x)+3)^2}}=\frac{2\sqrt2x}{\sqrt3}+\frac{\sqrt2(1-2x)}{\sqrt3}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=\frac{1}{3}$,which says that we got a maximal value.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an easier way: notice that $f(x)$ can be rewritten as
$$f(x) = 2g(x) + g(1-2x)$$
where
$$g(x) = \frac{x\sqrt{x+1}}{(9x^2+3)^\frac 14}$$

if you differentiate $f(x)$, you get
$$f'(x) = 2g'(x) -2g'(1-2x)$$
the maxima occurs when $f'(x) = 0$, or $2g'(x) = 2g'(1-2x) \implies x = 1-2x$. Solving this gives us $\boxed{x = \frac 13}$

Comment: I like this approach, but how can we be sure of the fact that $1/3$ is the only critical point ?

Comment: good question; $f'(x)$ actually has two roots, one being $1/3$ and the other being something very close to (but less than) $0.5$. I just saw the pattern and decided to go where it would lead me (which I'm afraid is not very rigorous).